# Converting table drawn as annotation in AutoCAD to format suitable to link attributes to cables in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, annotation, autocad

I am working on cables and each cable has attributes.

I want to link these attributes to the cables in ArcGIS for Desktop.

When I open these cables in AutoCAD it appears that their attributes are drawn as annotation. I would like these attributes to be in a table.

Later I need to export the data to an Excel spreadsheet.

There is an example of the Table open in AutoCAD below.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't happen to be attributes to block objects? If so, use [this guide](http://synergiscadblog.com/2013/03/26/how-to-convert-autocad-blocks-to-a-civil-3d-point-file-in-10-steps/) to export those attributes to excel/csv.

Comment: If they're just text strings in CAD then the two fastest options are probably either to simply retype the table, or if it's a large one print a pdf and import that to Excel or output an image and run it through OCR.

Comment: Based on your edit, this sounds like it might be a job for an extract data tool like [this one](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-6be7.htm,topicNumber=d0e81781). I haven't used AutoCAD in a while and never really used any of the data extraction. I see a tutorial [here](http://www.cadalyst.com/cad/autocad/tell-me-all-you-know-attribute-extraction-part-1-learning-curve-autocad-tutorial-6271) as well.